# Download Div & Canvas As One Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, html2canvas

I have a div with a background image set, on top of that I have a HTML canvas where I allow people to stick their own image and edit the size and position. (Essentially like a t-shirt design tool - [TeeSpring](http://teespring.com/))

I want to be able to combine the div and canvas and download it as an image. How would I do this? (Preferably using javascript/jquery).

I've tried using html2canvas and cavas2image but it didn't download the image in the canvas nor the background image of the div. Below is the HTML I have for div + canvas:

```
<div id="bottle-designer">
    <canvas id="editorCanvas" width="100" height="275"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You don't provide your current code, so here is a narrative explanation of how to achieve your task...**

When your Tee-design is complete, draw your "background" image from the div onto the canvas and then use `canvas.toDataURL` to export the canvas content as an image url.

You can use `destination-over` compositing to draw the background image behind the existing canvas content.

You can accomplish all this with javascript.